# How to make API Login Authentication in React-Native

Tags: react-native, api, authentication

I'm not exact sure how to make basic api login authentication with email and password. I'm stuck into here. If someone can help. That's my code:

```
class LoginScreen extends Component {

  constructor(){
           super();
           this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            result: false,
           }
       }

    _userLogin() {
         var email = this.state.username;
         var password = this.state.password;
         if (email && password) { // if validation fails, value will be null
           fetch("https://URL/api/login", {
             method: "POST",
             headers: {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({
               username: email,
               password: password,
             })
           })
           .then((response) => response.json())
           .then((responseData) => {
             console.log(responseData);
             AlertIOS.alert(
               "Login Success!"
             ),
             this._onValueChange(STORAGE_KEY, responseData.id_token)
           })
           .done();
           renderResults();
         }
       }

       handleEmail = (text) => {
             this.setState({ email: text })
       }

       handlePassword = (text) => {
             this.setState({ password: text })
       }
```

and then how to use it in the input fields and the button.

Comment: please add more details into your question mention what did you need to do

Comment: I need to make basic api login authentication, and need someone to show me how, I'm not sure is this working. And then how to use it in the email/pass fields and button

Comment: What navigation library are you using?

Comment: React-Navigation

Comment: Hey, search for basic react native tutorials with some user login features. Follow along and if you have doubts about specific details you can ask here.

Comment: I did it already. I can't find example with api authentication